# Сочетание слов "возможный результат"

Tags: выбор-слов, общие-вопросы, терминология

На работе заполняем таблицу с информацией о выполненных работах. Например, провели техническое обследование по подключению к интернету клиента. Есть столбец "результат". Руководством даны 3 варианты для заполнения: 1-"положительный", 2-"отрицательный", 3-"возможный". Я не согласен с тем, что можно написать "Результат - возможный". Я пишу так - "Возможно". Т.е. смысл такой: Подключить клиента к интернету возможно, но для этого нужно ...
Мне говорят, что слово "результат" мужского рода, значит надо писать "возможный".
Как мне объяснить, что это неправильно? Применительно к тому, что уже произошло. Т.е. техническое обследование проведено и его результат - "возможный".

Answer (score 2):

Потому что сочетание «возможный результат» означает результат, который вообще физически может быть. Если вам нужно угадать пол человека, то возможный результат — это мужчина и женщина. Возможный результат выпадения случайного числа в диапазоне от одного до десяти — любое число от одного до десяти. Результат тех. обследования, при котором проведение интернета возможно, но только после тех манипуляций, которые в ваших возможностях, можно назвать: «условно-положительный результат» или «потенциально положительный результат».